# Delete row Jtable Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-jtable

I am having problems deleting rows, I think is because the post[id] is not being sent. The delete message displays but the row is not deleted. Here is my code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Tabla de Clientes',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'Nombre ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: 'AccionesClientes.php?action=list',
            createAction: 'AccionesClientes.php?action=create',
            updateAction: 'AccionesClientes.php?action=update',
            deleteAction: 'AccionesClientes.php?action=delete',
        },
        fields: {
            id: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
        edit: false,
        list: false
            },
```

PHP:

```
else if($GET["action"] == "delete")
{
//Delete from database
$result = mysqlquery("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id= ".$_POST["id"].";");

    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

Can anybody see where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wasn't giving any value to the id field on the LIST method

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT **id as id**, nombre as Nombre, apellido1 as Apellido1, cedula as Cedula, empresa as Empresa, nit as Nit  FROM clientes ORDER BY " . $_GET["jtSorting"] . " LIMIT " . $_GET["jtStartIndex"] . "," . $_GET["jtPageSize"] . ";");
```

This solves the problem.